# call sagemaker endpoint using lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have some data in S3 and I want to create a lambda function to predict the output with my deployed aws sagemaker endpoint then I put the outputs in S3 again. Is it necessary in this case to create an api gateway like decribed in this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/call-an-amazon-sagemaker-model-endpoint-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) ? and in the lambda function what I have to put. I expect to put (where to find the data, how to invoke the endpoint, where to put the data)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you definitely don't have to create an API in API Gateway. You can invoke the endpoint directly using the invoke_endpoint() API, passing the endpoint name, the content type, and the payload.

For example:

```
import boto3

endpoint_name = <INSERT_ENDPOINT_NAME>
runtime = boto3.Session().client(service_name='sagemaker-runtime',region_name='us-east-1')

response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, ContentType='application/x-image', Body=payload)
print(response['Body'].read())
```

More examples here using a Lambda function: https://medium.com/@julsimon/using-chalice-to-serve-sagemaker-predictions-a2015c02b033

Comment: thank you for your response but that's not exactly my problem can you please see this new issue which more clarify  [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629890/invoke-aws-sagemaker-endpoint)  thank you

Comment: @Julien Simon, Could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379081/lambda-function-not-able-to-invoke-sagemaker-endpoint?noredirect=1#comment105238933_59379081 and let know what's going on wrong here. I believe it has to do with JSON request format.