# how to call sagemaker endpoint from another server

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I try to call aws sagemaker endpoint. but I don't use lambda function. only, I want to acess endpoint ARN, URL.

if impossible method, I want to know lambda function

my endpoint based keras model. I don't know json.dumps

```py
import json 
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

import numpy as np
test = np.zeros((1, 1, 4325))
test[0][0][1] = 1

data = {"instances": test.tolist()} 
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                                  Body=json.dumps(data))
response_body = response['Body'] 
print(response_body.read())
```

Comment: So what's your question / problem ? Maybe this example will help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/

Answer (score 2):

Your question It's a little bit confusing. I understand you want to call a deployed endpoint outside Sagemaker and You can do this as shown here [call-sagemaker-endpoint-using-lambda-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558832/call-sagemaker-endpoint-using-lambda-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call it using awscurl like that:

```
awscurl --profile aws-profile -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data @input_file_name  https://runtime.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/endpoints/your-endpoint-name/invocations --service sagemaker
```

You may want to also try with enviornment variable
export AWS_PROFILE=aws-profile; before the call to be sure you don't have something else set.